# How to build this sql query

Tags: sql

Table: sometbl

```
field1|field2|field3
txt1  |txt2  |1,5,7,4
txt3  |txt4  |1,7,8,9
txt5  |txt6  |8,3
```

How to select all from sometbl where field3 contains 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) table.

You can use the [`LIKE`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometbl
WHERE field3 LIKE '%1%'
```

Edit:

This, of course will also match `11`, `10`, `101` etc...

If you know `1` can only exist in the start, you can use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometbl
WHERE field3 LIKE '1,%' 
OR field3 = '1'
```

If `1` can appear anywhere, this will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometbl
WHERE field3 LIKE '1,%' 
OR field3 LIKE '%,1' 
OR field3 LIKE '%,1,%' 
OR field3 = '1'
```

Though the best option is to normalize.

Comment: Then use:   `WHERE field3 LIKE '%1,%'`  - better yet: normalize your table!

Comment: @nhnb, @lam3r4370 - correct. However, you did not specify the possibility of 101, or 10 existing...

Comment: @marc_s, `'%1,%'` isn't much better than `'%1%` :)

Comment: @Constantin - any option involving `LIKE` is suboptimal here, as I am sure you already know.

Comment: @COnstantin: true - the **best** solution would be to not have these kind of constructions in the first place - this is **always** going to be a mess and a hack......

Answer (score 1):

If comma-separated values are numbers, not digits, don't use just `LIKE '%1%'`, it will include "5,21" and "14,65" as well. If that's the case, you can use something hacky like `SELECT * FROM sometbl WHERE field3 LIKE '%,1' OR field3 LIKE '%,1,%' OR field3 LIKE '1,%' OR field3 = '1'`. Messy, but semantically correct.

Comment: But anyway, you're better off spending some time normalizing your database, it'll save you a lot of time and effort in future

Answer (score 0):

If `field3` is text, use [the `LIKE` operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM sometbl
WHERE field3 LIKE '%,1' OR field3 LIKE '1,%' OR field3 LIKE '%,1,%'
```